# Sml-mode won't work in Emacs, displays "Searching for program: permission denied"

Tags: windows, emacs, sml-mode

I'm working with `sml` right now and I'm trying to use emacs to compile my code with the command `ctrl-c`, `ctrl-b`. I´ve installed the  sml-mode in emacs but it still doesn't work

So this is what I'm typing:

`ctrl-c ctrl-b`
->`sml command:poly`
->`Searching for program: permission denied, Poly`  (we are told to use poly).

and the same happens if I use sml.

`ctrl-c ctrl-b`
->`sml command:sml`
->`Searching for program: permission denied, sml.`

I don't get what I'm doing wrong?

By the way, I'm working on a pc with windows 7 installed.

Comment: Looks like you don't have poly in your path. Just try to launch poly from cmd.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem myself a couple of days ago, and I finaly got it to work the way I wanted. Here's what I did step by step:

1. Download SML/NJ from [here](http://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.75/) for Windows and install it on your computer (to see that the program runs without any problems open your command prompt (cmd) and type `sml` followed by enter. You should now see a prompt that says something like `Standard ML of New Jersey v110.75 [built: ...]`).
2. In Emacs, run the command `M-x list-packages` and look for the `sml-mode` in the list. Click on it and install the package (if you've already done this just ignore this step).
3. Close and restart Emacs, and the `sml-mode` package should now work!
4. Open your SML-file with the code in Emacs and run the command `C-c C-s`. This splits the window and creates an SML prompt in the new buffer. In this buffer, type `use "thenameofyourfile.sml";` and your code should compile in the prompt right away!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check - try dragging the file into emacs instead of double clicking on the file.